# How to calculate FOV from VRFrameData?

Tags: javascript, webgl, webvr

There used to be field of view information in the [`VREyeParameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VREyeParameters), but that was deprecated. So now i am wondering: Is possible to calculate that using the view/projection matrices provided by [`VRFrameData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRFrameData)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. The projection matrix transforms from view space to the clip space. Clip space coordinates are [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) in the range (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates.

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport. 
 The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image]

If you want to know the corners of the camera frustum in view space, then you have to transform the corners of the normalized device space (-1, -1, -1), ..., (1, 1, 1) by the **inverse projection matrix**. To get [cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), the X, Y, and Z component of the result has to be divided by the W (4th) component of the result.
[glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/) is a library which provides matrix operations and data types such as `mat4` and `vec4`:

```
projection  = mat4.clone( VRFrameData.leftProjectionMatrix );
inverse_prj = mat4.create();
mat4.invert( inverse_prj, projection );

pt_ndc = [-1, -1, -1];
v4_ndc = vec4.fromValues( pt_ndc[0], pt_ndc[1], pt_ndc[2], 1 );

v4_view = vec4.create();  
vec4.transformMat4( v4_view, v4_ndc, inverse_prj );
pt_view = [v4_view[0]/v4_view[3], v4_view[1]/v4_view[3], v4_view[2]/v4_view[3]];
```

The transformation view coordinates to world coordinates can be done by the **inverse view matrix**.

```
view         = mat4.clone( VRFrameData.leftViewMatrix );
inverse_view = mat4.create();
mat4.invert( inverse_view, view );

v3_view  = vec3.clone( pt_view );
v3_world = vec3.create();
mat4.transformMat4( v3_world, v3_view, inverse_view );
```

Note, the left and right projection matrix are not symmetric. This means the line of sight is not in the center of the frustum and they are different for the left and the right eye.

Further note, a perspective projection matrix looks like this:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

2*n/(r-l)      0              0                0
0              2*n/(t-b)      0                0
(r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    -1    
0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)     0
```

where :

```
a = w / h
ta = tan( fov_y / 2 );

2 * n / (r-l) = 1 / (ta * a)
2 * n / (t-b) = 1 / ta
```

**If the projection is symmetric**, where the line of sight is in the center of the view port and the field of view is not displaced, then the matrix can be simplified:

```
1/(ta*a)  0     0              0
0         1/ta  0              0
0         0    -(f+n)/(f-n)   -1    
0         0    -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

This means the field of view angle can be calculated by:

```
fov_y = Math.atan( 1/prjMat[5] ) * 2; // prjMat[5] is prjMat[1][1]
```

and the aspect ratio by:

```
aspect = prjMat[5] / prjMat[0];
```

The calculation for the field of view angle also works, if the projection matrix is only symmetric along the horizontal. This means if `-bottom` is equal to `top`. For the projection matrices of the 2 eyes this should be the case.

Furthermore:

```
z_ndc = 2.0 * depth - 1.0;
z_eye = 2.0 * n * f / (f + n - z_ndc * (f - n));
```

by substituting the fields of the projection matrix this is:

```
A = prj_mat[2][2]
B = prj_mat[3][2]
z_eye = B / (A + z_ndc)
```

This means the distance to the near plane and to the far plane can be calculated by:

```
A = prj_mat[10]; // prj_mat[10] is prj_mat[2][2]
B = prj_mat[14]; // prj_mat[14] is prj_mat[3][2]

near = - B / (A - 1);
far  = - B / (A + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very in-depth answer. Using the formula `Math.atan2(1, prjMat[5]) * 2` i seem to get the FOV about right but it looks like it is not quite centered, with everything being shifted a bit vertically. I will try to work this out using a projection and some basic trigonometry...

Comment: @H.B. If the field `prj_mat[2][1]` (`prj_mat[9]`)  is not 0.0, then the the projection is shifted vertically and of the field `prj_mat[2][0]` (`prj_mat[8]`)  is not 0.0, then the the projection is shifted horizontally.

Comment: Both are non-zero. There is a minor shift horizontally (symmetric, i.e. same number but inverted sign for both eyes) and a larger vertical shift which is identical for both eyes.

Comment: @H.B. In perspective projection the "shift" depends on the the Z coordinated (depth). Probably you have to calculate the 4 corner points of the near plane by the inverse projection matrix.

Answer (score 3):

[SOHCAHTOA](http://www.mathwords.com/s/sohcahtoa.htm) pronounced "So", "cah", "toe-ah"

- SOH -> Sine(angle) = Opposite over Hypotenuse
- CAH -> Cosine(angle) = Adjacent over Hypotenuse
- TOA -> Tangent(angle) = Opposite over Adjacent

[image]

Tells us the relationships of the various sides of a *right* triangle to various trigonometry functions

So looking at a frustum image we can take the right triangle from the eye to the near plane to the top of the frustum to compute the tangent of the field of view and we can use the arc tangent to turn a tangent back into an angle.

[image]

Since we know the result of the projection matrix takes our world space frustum and converts it to clip space and ultimately to normalized device space (-1, -1, -1) to (+1, +1, +1) we can get the positions we need by multiplying the corresponding points in NDC space by the inverse of the projection matrix

```
eye = 0,0,0
centerAtNearPlane = inverseProjectionMatrix * (0,0,-1)
topCenterAtNearPlane = inverseProjectionMatrix * (0, 1, -1)
```

Then

```
opposite = topCenterAtNearPlane.y
adjacent = -centerAtNearPlane.z
halfFieldOfView = Math.atan2(opposite, adjacent)
fieldOfView = halfFieldOfView * 2
```

Let's test

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const fovValueElem = document.querySelector("#fovValue");
const resultElem = document.querySelector("#result");
let fov = degToRad(45);

function updateFOV() {
  fovValueElem.textContent = radToDeg(fov).toFixed(1);
  
  // get a projection matrix from somewhere (like VR)
  const projection = getProjectionMatrix();
  
  // now that we have projection matrix recompute the FOV from it
  const inverseProjection = m4.inverse(projection);
  const centerAtZNear = m4.transformPoint(inverseProjection, [0, 0, -1]);
  const topCenterAtZNear = m4.transformPoint(inverseProjection, [0, 1, -1]);
  
  const opposite = topCenterAtZNear[1];
  const adjacent = -centerAtZNear[2];
  const halfFieldOfView = Math.atan2(opposite, adjacent);
  const fieldOfView = halfFieldOfView * 2;
  
  resultElem.textContent = radToDeg(fieldOfView).toFixed(1);
}

updateFOV();

function getProjectionMatrix() {
  // doesn't matter. We just want a projection matrix as though
  // someone else made it for us.
  const aspect = 2 / 1; 
  // choose some zNear and zFar
  const zNear = .5;
  const zFar = 100;
  return m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
}


function radToDeg(rad) {
  return rad / Math.PI * 180;
}

function degToRad(deg) {
  return deg / 180 * Math.PI;
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  fov = degToRad(parseInt(e.target.value));
  updateFOV();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<input id="fov" type="range" min="1" max="179" value="45"><label>fov: <span id="fovValue"></span></label>
<div>computed fov: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Note this assumes the center of the frustum is directly in front of the eye. If it's not then you'd probably have to compute `adjacent` by computing the length of the vector from the eye to centerAtZNear

```
const v3 = twgl.v3;

...

const adjacent = v3.length(centerAtZNear);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This method definitely works, but getting the values straight from one of the matrix cells as suggested by Rabbid76 is less complicated and probably faster.

Comment: actually there are other ways to make projection matricies. his answer assumes which one is being used.